# Softmax Output Layer. Which dimension?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, image-segmentation, deeplab

I am having a question regarding Neuronal Nets used for image segmentation. I am using a 3D Implementation of Deeplab that can be found [here](https://github.com/ChoiDM/pytorch-deeplabv3plus-3D)

I am using `softmax`, so the output layer is the following:

```py
elif self.last_activation.lower() == 'softmax':
        output = nn.Softmax()(output)
```

No dimension is defined, so I want to define it manually. But I am not sure which dimension I need tó set. The dimension of the output tensor is the following:

```
[batch_size, num_classes, width, height, depth]
```

So I would think that `dim=1` would be correct. Is that correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it should be 1 as you want this axis to be summed to 1.
Be careful if you need to train your network with a crossentropyloss as this latter already include a softmax.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for that answer! I am indeed training with cross entropy loss and I am facing some difficulties. Could you explain to me in which ways I need to be careful and how I could avoid problems? Thanks!!

Comment: From the official pytorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html), their crossentropy loss function already include a logsofmax. So in the case you need to train your network, you should remove the nn.Softmax layer otherwise you will apply softmax two times which affects the output.